# What is the best way of maintaining proxy server addresses for apt and other stuff?

Tags: 14.04, apt, proxy

I have seen a lot of posts but couldn't find a simple answer that summarizes everything.

I am new so I am still confused.

Thanks :)

Comment: If that is not what you need explain what part you do not understand.

Comment: Its not just about apt, I want a solution summarizing proxy setting for everything.

Comment: Use network manager - http://www.unixmen.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/moz1.png and http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-configure-ubuntu-desktop-to-use-your-proxy-server.html .

Comment: I don't understand why this is duplicate. 
1. This question is not just for apt.
2. This question is about seeking a best routine for proxy configs, and as the voted answer suggests, there are many.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As there a lot of places to configure proxy settings, it might get confusing at beginning. Let me summarize some things and suggest some good practices.

### For console programs

Ex:  wget, git and almost every console application which connects to internet.

If you want to configure proxy every time you run your commands for some reason then **set the environment variables** using following commands.

```
export http_proxy=http://DOMAIN\USERNAME:PASSWORD@SERVER:PORT/
export ftp_proxy=http://DOMAIN\USERNAME:PASSWORD@SERVER:PORT/
```

Else if you want to use the same settings everytime for all users, then use of these.

**Configure in bashrc**

```
$ nano /etc/bash.bashrc
export http_proxy=http://DOMAIN\USERNAME:PASSWORD@SERVER:PORT/
export ftp_proxy=http://DOMAIN\USERNAME:PASSWORD@SERVER:PORT/
```

**Configure in `/etc/environment`**

```
$ nano /etc/environment
https_proxy="http://myproxy.server.com:8080/" 
ftp_proxy="http://myproxy.server.com:8080/" ...
```

**Configure using GUI**

Open the network settings and set the your system wide network proxy.

Network -> Network proxy -> Configure -> Apply system wide.

But this might not be useful if you have authentication for the proxy.

### For apt.

You need to do some extra work for apt, as incidentally apt doesn't obey environment variables,

```
$ nano /etc/apt/apt.conf
Acquire::http::Proxy "http://USERNAME:PASSWORD@SERVER:PORT";
Acquire::https::Proxy "https://USERNAME:PASSWORD@SERVER:PORT";
```

---

For everything out of this scope, there must be an option to configure proxy settings in the application itself. If not I'm sorry ;)

Comment: This summarizes most of my doubts, but why is it that apt needs one more step for configuration ?

Comment: I am not sure to be honest, you might what to add another question for this. :)

Comment: Actually, `apt-get` has, for some versions, now, supported the `http_proxy` and `https_proxy` environment variables.